# How can Angular-cli's config be modified to allow for an in-memory backend?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Going off the Angular2 Tutorial, in order for the in memory backend to work properly, there have to be package settings in system-config.ts as follows:

```
packages: {
'app': { main: './main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'api' : { defaultExtension : 'js' },
'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
}
```

I've put together an Angular2 app, and I'm using Angular-api to bundle for production.  However, Angular-api uses webpack, which doesn't seem to have a comparable configuration file to set the default extensions.  My app can be built and served without error, but when loading the page my data grabbing service is non-functional and I get the following error:

`error_handler.js:47EXCEPTION: unable to parse url './projects'; original error: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

There are some Angular-cli configuration files buried within the node_modules folder, but none seem to involve packages or default extensions.  I'd be super grateful for any help.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you are using the CLI for production and dev or not? It's an easy solution if you are using the angular-cli.

Comment: The intent is to use the CLI for production.  It appears to be minifying and bundling everything correctly, I'm only having issues with the in memory backend data service.

Comment: Do you have the package installed in your package.json? You should see a line under "dependencies" like so: "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.1.15".

Comment: Yes, here it is: `"angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.1.15"`

Comment: Do you get any errors when you build locally? With: ng build -prod?

Comment: I get the `Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events` warning, and a bunch of UglifyJS unused function warnings, but that's all.

Comment: Can you do ng serve? And see if that works? There is a problem with using the CLI and the in memory service, but you might be missing the error being lost in all the other logs.

Comment: The same problem happens with ng serve, giving the same error about being unable to parse the url.

Answer (score 0):

The CLI has a known incompatibility with the angular-in-memory-web-api, or more specifically, how it uses core-js. If you look through your log on the console, you will see this error:

```
Cannot find type definition file for 'core-js'.
```

To fix that, do this:

1. Install the core-js typing with: npm install --save @types/core-js
2. Edit tsconfig.json and set the "lib" value to "es5". It should look like this:

`{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
        "mapRoot": "./",
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
          "../node_modules/@types"
        ]
      }
    }`